# Simple file manipulation application, does a new instance help or hurt?

Tags: c#, instance

Consider this code and bear in mind I primarily deal with JavaScript and T-SQL:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    logToEventLog("Task Started", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    p.moveAndRenameAllFiles();
    p.processReports();
    logToEventLog("Task Ended", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

Versus

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    logToEventLog("Task Started", EventLogEntryType.Information);
    moveAndRenameAllFiles();
    processReports();
    logToEventLog("Task Ended", EventLogEntryType.Information);
}
```

The first method does exactly what it says.  The second method inserts the file into the database, grabbing some information from the file name for identification.

In this comparison, is there a value I don't see in initializing a separate instance?

Comment: Did you try it out? Benchmark it? See any observable difference in behavior? If not, which is more readable and more understandable?

Comment: @mason I ran it through the debugger both ways with no visible difference.  At the end of the day it will work both ways, I just don't know if one way is really *better* than the other.

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: @mason in any way.  I don't see the point in the first scenario and was preparing to move forward with the second, but thought I would ask the experts first.  ;-)

Comment: In this case there will be no appreciable difference.  Allocation in C# is quick due to how the GC manages your heap.  Everything you do here would be dominated by the IO cost. 

If you had millions of allocations then perhaps you migt be able to tell a difference.

Comment: If they both function the same, and have identical performance, then it usually comes down to "which is simpler and easier to read"

Comment: In this case, the second bit of code is clearly preferable, since I presume your Main method is actually part of your Program class. But let's say `moveAndRenameAllFiles` and `processReports` were placed in a separate class called ReportProcessor and that ReportProcessor was placed in a separate class library. Now you could call that logic from other code besides just your console app. Of course in this highly simplified scenario you've shown, that doesn't appear necessary at all.

Comment: For such a trivial example, I'm not sure it matters. Perhaps, if this were the formative steps of a larger application, then instances are advantageous because they can implement interfaces etc etc. However for a 2 liner? It doesn't really matter and is a matter of personal opinion. Hence my close-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only useful thing that comes from keeping `Program` an instance is a possibility of the object to keep state without employing static variables.

For example, if `moveAndRenameAllFiles` would store some data that is later used by `processReports`, doing the same thing in the static context would require using static variables.

Apart from helping your ability to test your implementation, absence of static variables helps in situations when you must refactor to run a few instances of `Program`'s methods concurrently - for example, when dealing with multiple network locations.

There is no advantage for "stateless" implementations.

Comment: Fantastic.  In my case we are not doing multiple locations, just one repository for the files.